# How to modify the url in plone so that we don't get the same page if it is modified?

Tags: python, plone

After using atreal.richfile.preview in plone, we get the preview of a pdf file with the url like : `http://localhost:8090/plone/sample.pdf/view`. If we delete part of the url i.e "/view", and enter the url: `http://localhost:8090/plone/sample.pdf` in the browser, it still can be viewed and the pdf becomes printable or can be copied. How can I modify the url so that it will not display the pdf in the new window if the url of the same is modified? Using plone 4.1. Which template and what code needs to be added/ edited. Please guide

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The question in the title doesn't really correlate with the question in the body.

Comment: @Tim Lamballais all I want to do is , if url is modified manually(prefix/postfix added/deleted) it should not render the same page which in this case does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the example above, sample.pdf is presumably a File created in Plone. In this case, the URL without /view will render the file for download, and the URL with /view will render a Plone page with a link to download it. This is standard behaviour.

It isn't really possible to stop people from downloading the PDF. You can modify the File FTI in portal_types (go to portal_types/File in the ZMI and change the method aliases tab). If you change the "(Default)" alias to be the same as the "view" one, it will behave the same. Note that this will affect all files.

Martin

Comment: this is what I have been looking for, Thx a lot :)